# Где определено, что менеджер контекста with вместе с RLock() неявно вызывает метод lock.acquire()? Как изучающим Python понимать подобное самим?

Tags: python

Изучаю Python. Тщательно, с интересом. Долго пытался понять, как же работает пример с сочетанием типа with RLock() без вызова потом в тексте необходимых методов lock.acquire() и lock.release(). В описаниях RLock или with на docs-python.ru/ указаний на это не увидел. В конце концов нагуглил, что "Оператор with в этом случае вызывает lock.acquire() при входе и lock.release() при выходе." (https://digitology.tech/posts/kontekstnye-menedzhery-v-python/)
А как изучающие Phyton это должены понять сами (своими мозгами)? Из чего это следует?
(Хорошо, если бы ответ затронул и потенциально схожие проблемы)

Пример кода:

```
    class Example1:
        def __init__(self):
            self.lock = RLock()

        def example_of_method (self):
            with self.lock:
                print ('lock.acquire() was just called somehow')
```

Comment: Пользуйтесь только официальной документацией.

Comment: Спасибо. Я правильно понимаю, что на русском официальной нет?

Comment: Правильно, нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это описано в [документации](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/library/threading.html). В [разделе](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/library/threading.html#rlock-objects)  про RLock последний абзац:

> Reentrant locks also support the [context management protocol](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/library/threading.html#with-locks).

А по [ссылке](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/library/threading.html#with-locks) это описано подробно и с примером:

> All of the objects provided by this module that have acquire() and release() methods can be used as context managers for a with statement. The acquire() method will be called when the block is entered, and release() will be called when the block is exited. Hence, the following snippet:
>
> ```
> with some_lock:
>     # do something...
> ```
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> some_lock.acquire()
> try:
>    # do something...
> finally:
>    some_lock.release()
> ```

Comment: Роман, спасибо, ясно, полезный ответ на будущее по всем подобным случаям, хорошо, что я спросил. Документация на сайте, где читал на русском - урезана. Я правильно понимаю, что вообще лучше всё читать на английском - полных сайтов с русским переводом нет? (я знаю английский, русский, правда, получше).
VPN для этого сайта с документацией нужен, кстати.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, ещё это можно понять чисто по логике. При использовании контекстного менеджера `with` при заходе в блок вызывается метод `__enter__`, при выходе `__exit__`. А дальше нужно смотреть - что именно вызывается в этих методах. Можно либо посмотреть исходники библиотеки и увидеть, что там как-раз и вызываются `acquire` и `release`, либо можно через `dir()` посмотреть, какие есть публичные методы у `self.lock` и увидеть, что их собственно всего два этих метода и один из них должен вызываться при входе в блок, а другой при выходе. Без вариантов в данном случае, у объекта, создаваемого через `RLock()`, просто нет никаких других публичных методов для вызова.

Comment: спасибо. Несколько сложноват этот путь, особо для начинающего (с документацией всё же более классически), хотя и интересен. 1) Я, кстати, сам до размещения вопроса про __enter__ почитал в связи с этим, но не догадался смотреть внутрь методов. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исходники библиотеки смотреть? 2) Про dir () - да, спасибо, есть там 'acquire', 'release' действительно. Но это же ещё догадаться надо, что они при старте могут вызываться, чтобы туда посмотреть. 3) Извините, почему-то имя "@CrazyElf" не впечатывается в начале - исчезает после нажатия "сохранить изменения").

Comment: 1) исходники легко гуглятся, но разобраться где там реализация конкретных объектов, учитывая наследование, не всегда просто https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/threading.py 2) ну так то да, но список методов всегда полезно посмотреть 3) поскольку вы комментируете именно мой ответ, движок считает, что меня можно не упоминать, и так понятно, что это ответ именно мне по умолчанию )

Comment: Спасибо. Да, в этом коде копаться - явно не для текущих приоритетов начинающих изучение языка.